# Stop execution of previous code STM32F4Discovery

Tags: c, embedded, reset, stm32f4discovery

I have tried a simple Blinking LED program on my STM32F4 Discovery board by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_3390219531&feature=iv&src_vid=Nvyncl8y7-Q&v=kHyhAlvIngk) tutorial.

However, I am not sure how to stop this from running, i.e., when I unplug the device from the PC and plug it in, I would expect it to reset itself (I might be wrong too, please correct me if this is not the case).

The board keeps blinking the LED on connecting it again. How do I reset it to its original state? Pointers to references for embedded programming would also be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean "reset itself"?  You have programmed the flash of the micro to blink a light.  That's all it knows how to do now.  Any time the board is powered it will run that program.  To put it back to it's "original state", you'll have to load the original program back into the flash.

Comment: By resetting itself, I mean to go back to its original state.  I am pretty new to embedded programming. How should I load the original program back into the flash to stop the LED from blinking. Could you provide pointers to some references that I could follow. @Ross

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Go to the official page for the discovery board: http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF252419  Look at the related tools and software section.  That should provide you with some options for firmware to load back into the micro.  And search around on the internet for some embedded basics...  It's too broad of a topic for us to successfully teach you here.

Answer (score 1):

If "original state" means the program that was shipped with the board, then you can probably download that at ST's website.  You'll need to program the chip's flash with that stock binary.

Note that by programming the board you're programming the flash memory which will retain its contents through power cycles.